# SWT: Print browser-widget contents

Tags: java, browser, printing, swt

My apologies if this is something obvious that I have missed - strange enough a quick google and SO-Search revealed nothing:

I am using an SWT-Browser widget within an Eclipse-RCP view to show local HTML-Content. How can I print it?

Yes I know I can right-click into the window and select print, but I need something more user-friendly like a "Print"-Button the user can click.
There is no `print()`-Method for the widget, so how can I call the context-menu "print" or bring up the printing-dialog otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use javascript to print the contents of the window.

```
browser.execute("javascript:window.print();");
```

Comment: Yes, but then i need a "print-button" within the HTML-Content, which i dont like too much. I'd prefer to have a print-button in some toolbar which calls a print-function..
Still, its a way to go if there is no better option - thanks for that!

Comment: @quaylar `browser.execute()` is called from Java code, so no need for an HTML button.

Answer (score 1):

You might use JavaScript's `print()` function [see tutorial for details](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471121/Print-a-Web-Page-Using-JavaScript.htm) and run it from your [Java code if you want](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/BrowsermodifyDOMexecutingjavascript.htm).

Comment: Hah - +1 for the Browser.execute() function - how could i miss that :)